# ¿Cómo hacer que un método se ejecute si otro no lo hace?

Tags: java, android

Como veis en mi código al hacer clic en el primer inicio en `btn_flo_1` se ejecuta el método `abrirGuia` y guarda en mi `SharedPreference` que no vuelva a activarse el método `abrirGuia` pues ahora viene mi problema, necesito que cuando no active ese método, active este `editarPersona(0);` 
¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

```
    btn_flo_1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {

            // guardar y comprueba si es el primer inicio o no

                        Boolean isFirstRun = getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferenceApp", MODE_PRIVATE)
                                .getBoolean("isfirstrun", true);

                        if (isFirstRun) {

                            // metodo para abrir la clase GuiaParte2

                            abrirGuia();

//

                            getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferenceApp", MODE_PRIVATE)
                                    .edit().putBoolean("isfirstrun", false).commit();
                        }

                        // cierra el menu de boton

                        btn_flo_menu.close(true);
                    }
                });

            }
```

Comment: else editarPersona(0);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 btn_flo_1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {

            // guardar y comprueba si es el primer inicio o no

                    Boolean isFirstRun = getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferenceApp", MODE_PRIVATE)
                                .getBoolean("isfirstrun", true);

                    if (isFirstRun) {

                        // metodo para abrir la clase GuiaParte2
                        abrirGuia();
//  
                        getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferenceApp", MODE_PRIVATE)
                                    .edit().putBoolean("isfirstrun", false).commit();
                    } else {
                        editarPersona(0);
                    }

                    // cierra el menu de boton

                    btn_flo_menu.close(true);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Gracias! Solucionado, solo necesita un `else` ! Gracias =)

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que duplicas el `MotionEvent` en tu @Override aquí:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
    this.detector.onTouchEvent(me); // aquí causas procesamiento del click
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(me); // aquí lo causas de nuevo en forma regular
}
```

El método `dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent m)` causa la llamada a `onTouchEvent` en la `View` y todos sus vistas hijos, el método debe devolver `true` en caso que el evento fue consumido o `false` en el caso que no. Si quieres trabajar con evaluar el `OnTouchEvent` directo en vez del `OnClickListener`, podrías usar eso para diferenciar entre eventos ya consumidos y eventos que deben ser redistribuidos. En todo caso no es ideal de llamar a `onTouchEvent` manualmente si quieres evitar repetición de procesamiento de eventos.

Comment: Yo creo que el error más bien está en el botón `btn_flo_1` que ejecuta el método `editarPersona(0);` ejecute o no `abrirGuia();` no crees? Pero no sé como solucionarlo, gracias por tu respuesta @StefanNolde

Comment: Bueno, preguntaste porque tu código llama a `editarPersonas(0)` dos veces, y eso es la respuesta. Si crees que el problema es otro, eso es todo tu derecho. Te puedo explicar un poco más por qué.

Comment: Bueno, he probado lo que me comentas, pero si borro "this.det....." simplemente no puedo hacer el gesto en la pantalla para abrir el método, y si borro el `return` no puedo compilar.. @StefanNolde por eso pienso que debería comprobar en`MainActivity` si se ejecuta `abrirGuia();` y si se ejecuta que no lo haga `editarPersona(0);` , este último método solo se debería ejecutar si `abrirGuia();` no lo hace @StefanNolde lo añado a la pregunta

Comment: yo creo que con un flag lo podrias solucionar

Comment: Edite la pregunta @ArmandoBarreda